# <# Syntax in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, wordpress-theming

I was just viewing source of a Wordpress Admin Screen and I noticed the `<#` kind of syntax. Please see the screenshot attached as well. I wanted to know what language or markup is that?[image]

Comment: it's undoubtedly Yet Another Templating Engine, because PHP itself is so utterly horrible for generating/outputting html </sarcasm>

Comment: It's a templating system

Answer (score 1):

If you look into `wp-includes/js/wp-util.js`, you'll find the following function that parse those tags:

```
wp.template = _.memoize(function ( id ) {
    var compiled,
        /*
         * Underscore's default ERB-style templates are incompatible with PHP
         * when asp_tags is enabled, so WordPress uses Mustache-inspired templating syntax.
         *
         * @see trac ticket #22344.
         */
        options = {
            evaluate:    /<#([\s\S]+?)#>/g,
            interpolate: /\{\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}\}/g,
            escape:      /\{\{([^\}]+?)\}\}(?!\})/g,
            variable:    'data'
        };

    return function ( data ) {
        compiled = compiled || _.template( $( '#tmpl-' + id ).html(), null, options );
        return compiled( data );
    };
});
```

As the comment explain, [they changed](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22344) the template tag `<% %>` to [Mustache tags](https://mustache.github.io/) in version 3.5 to avoid any conflict with asp tags.